# selenium script has to run continuously in server with out using eclipse

Tags: selenium

is it possible to run selenium script in server without using eclipse or command prompt.for every fixed time intervals my selenium script has to run automatically in backend with out any browser opening

Comment: Which is the server used? If you want headless execution then you can use phantom js. also if you want automatic execution then you can use jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

This can be split into two questions;

**Can I schedule a Selenium test?**

Yes, there are many options including using a CI tool such as Jenkins, Hudson, Team City,etc. Alternatively you could write a shell script to run the command line, and schedule this to run every x hours.

**Can I run Selenium without opening a browser?**

Yes. As mentioned before you could go headless, but depending on complexity of your application and test, you may find headless is not suitable.  However, you can use RemoteWebdriver to launch a browser on a different machine but the test would still be run on your back end, it would just be the browse launched remotely.  See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2 and https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriverServer